# How to send enter as an input in console application

Tags: cmd, command, prompt

I want to create a console application and want to send command prompt commands
but I dont know how to send enter in it

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
    Console.Write("tree")

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Isn't this VB, not C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `Enter` as the termination of input. How do you alert the console that you finish your input?

Suppose that you press `X` to terminate the input.

You can use `do while` loop runs to listen what you press (including the `Enter` to break line) until you press `X`. Something like:

```
        public static string CustomReadline()
        {
            string s = "";
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
            do
            {
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }                    
                s += keyinfo.KeyChar.ToString();
            }
            while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.X);

            return s;
        }
```

and you call the method to receive the input

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = CustomReadline();
    }
```